# Instruction Meeting or Introductory Meeting?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which of the following two constructions is correct? Instruction Meeting or Introductory Meeting? The context is the title of a business meeting that is supposed to happen in the future, not with a team member or friend.

Comment: There is no way to answer this.  "Instruction" and "Introductory" are completely different.  Did you mean "Introduction" instead of "Instruction"?

Answer (score 0):

An instruction meeting usually refers to a meeting where one gives instructions and delegates the work to others, while an introductory meeting is where one gives an "introduction" on a topic to others to give a brief explanation about something.

Comment: An _introductory meeting_ could also be a gathering of new staff at which their managers can introduce themselves and talk about things that newcomers need to know.